# Iterate through a group of select controls and choose only the ones that have a specific selected value

Tags: jquery

I need to iterate through a group of select lists on my page and choose only those selects that have the selected option of "Yes".

Something like (which doesnt work):

```
$(".option-select option[value='yes']:selected").each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), or to be safer(`<optgroup>` for example), [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), like this:

```
$(".option-select option[value='yes']:selected").closest('select').each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Or [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$(".option-select").filter(function() { return $(this).val() == "yes"; }).each(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Instead of iterating the collction, say i wanted to just create a jQuery collection of all the selects that, could I just do this:

Comment: @StephenLewes - If you wanted an array of IDs for example, you could use `.map()` like this: `var idArray = $(".option-select").filter(function() { return $(this).val() == "yes"; }).map(function() { return this.id; }).get();`

Comment: Nick, youre obviously a jQuery guru and thanks for your help. The final step of this is to pass this array back to the server using the .post() method. However I think I need to serialize the array but this doesnt seem to work. Can you help? $.post("/Quote/GetOptionPrice", idArray.serialize(), function (response) { $(".price").html(response); });

Comment: @StephenLewes - You just need to pass it as an object, for example `$.post("/Quote/GetOptionPrice", { myParam: idArray }, function (response) { $(".price").html(response); });`